# Suitable way to parse XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xmlpullparser

Can anyone advise me a suitable (and fast) ways to parse XML (especially RSS) file in Android? Please don't advise `XmlPullParser` because it's completelly unacceptable. It could blow up minds.

Comment: You could try out Jackson's XML extension: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Comment: @DanailAlexiev make this as an answer

Comment: Whats wrong with XmlPullParser?

Comment: @user1282637 it takes too much of code for common task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try out Jackson's XML extension: github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml